# Expected Length of Walk on Truncated Icosahedron

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, random-walk, polyhedra, mental-arithmetic

Consider a truncated icosahedron with 12 pentagons and 20 hexagons. Starting from a hexagonal face, we go to any neighboring polygon randomly with equal probability. What is the expected number of steps it takes for us to visit the starting hexagon a second time?

I know that this is easily solvable with a Markov Chain, but the question specifically requires little computation, stating that the problem can be finished with just simple mental math. I know the answer to be 30, but I cannot find an elegant way to assert so.

One argument is that since 3/2 is the expected number of steps from one hexagon to another, and there are 20 hexagons, that the answer is simply 3/2 times 20, which is 30. However, this clearly lacks rigor.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry of the Markov chain associated with the random walk enables you to calculate the expected return time fairly easily.  The chain has $\ 32\ $ states $\ h_1,h_2,\dots,h_{20},p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{12}\ ,$ where $\ h_i\ $ are the hexagonal faces and $\ p_i\ $ the pentagonal faces.  If $\ \pi\ $ is the stationary distribution of the chain, then by symmetry we must have
$$
\pi_{h_i}=\pi_{h_j}=\mathfrak{h}\ ,
$$
say, for all $\ i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,20\}\ ,$ and
$$
\pi_{p_i}=\pi_{p_j}=\mathfrak{p}\ ,
$$
say, for all $\ i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,12\}\ ,$ with
$$
20\mathfrak{h}+12\mathfrak{p}=1
$$
and
$$
\mathfrak{h}=\frac{\mathfrak{h}}{2}+\frac{3\mathfrak{p}}{5}\ ,
$$
because the entry to a hexagon from each of its three adjacent hexagons occurs with probability $\ \frac{1}{6}\ $, and the entry to it from each of its three adjacent pentagons occurs with probability $\ \frac{1}{5}\ $.  These solution to these equations is $\ \mathfrak{p}=\frac{1}{36}, \mathfrak{h}=\frac{1}{30}\ .$ It now follows from [one of the fundamental theorems](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Markov_chain,_ergodic&oldid=13601) of ergodic Markov chains that the expected first passage time from a hexagon to itself is $\ \frac{1}{\mathfrak{h}}=30\ .$